# How I can use/create themes in JSF?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, themes

I have one form, something like that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Some css file included here -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Form parameters like action, method omitted  for simplicity-->
        <form>
            <p class="someTextClass">msg[code.text]</p>
            <input class="someInputClass" type="text"/>
            <button class="someButtonClass">msg[code.button]</button>
            <p class="someHelpTextClass">msg[code3.help]</p>
        </form
    </body
</html>
```

But currently there are a lot of conditions statements like "(condition) ? messageOne : messageTwo" and "rendered" attributes. But I want to switch all text in tags and related css classes simultaneously (and not to lose i18n). I want to set a parameter in one place and switch all css and text according to it automatically. It there something similar in JSF? When I learned Spring there is something like themes in it, is there theme analog in JSF?

P.S. If something unclear in my explanation please write a comment and I"ll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to JSF 2.2? The notion of [resources and contracts](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/resource_library_contracts_in_jsf2) is what you are looking for.

Alternatively, you can potentially fetch the appropriate theme style from a backing bean:

```
webapp/
  resources/theme1/css/styles.css
  resources/theme2/css/styles.css


<h:outputStyleSheet library="#{someBean.theme}" name="css/styles.css"/>
```

Since outputStyleSheet can take an EL for the name as well, you can look at pushing that code to the bean as well.

For the pageTemplate itself, you should probably look at fetching that information from a bean.

Hope that helps.